# JScript help? What is the main purpose of  this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

What is the main purpose of the following JavaScript code?

```
<script>

var QunarUtil=new function(){var prefix='/scripts/';var suffix='';var host='';if(location.host.indexOf('src.')!=-1){prefix='/scripts/src/';host='http://hstatic.qunar.com';suffix='.js';}else if(location.host.indexOf('enc.')!=-1){prefix='/scripts/';host='http://hstatic.qunar.com';suffix='.js';}else if(location.host.substring(0,10)=='sdev-'){prefix=location.host.substring(5,location.host.indexOf('.'));prefix='/'+prefix.replace(/\-/ig,'/');host='http://hstatic.qunar.com';suffix='.js';}else if(location.host.indexOf("h.qunar.com")!=-1){host='http://hstatic.qunar.com';suffix='';}
this.getScriptURL=function(name,isList){if(name.charAt(0)!='/')
return this.getScript(prefix+name,isList);else
return this.getScript(name,isList);}
this.getScript=function(src,isList){return'<'+'script type="text/javascript" src="'+host+src+(isList?suffix:'.js')+'?'+__QUNARVER__+'"></'+'script>';}
this.writeScript=function(name,isList){document.write(this.getScriptURL(name,isList));}
this.writeScriptList=function(list){for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
document.write(this.getScriptURL(list[i]));}
var cssRoot='/styles/';this.writeCSS=function(cssList){for(var i=0;i<cssList.length;i++){document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+cssRoot+cssList[i]+'?'+__QUNARVER__+'">');}}
this.writeStaticScript=function(src){document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="'+src+'"></'+'scr'+'ipt>');}
this.writeStaticList=function(src){document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="'+src+suffix+'?'+__QUNARVER__+'"></'+'scr'+'ipt>');}}
$include=function(){for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){QunarUtil.writeScript(arguments[i],true);}}
</script>
```

---

Uncompressed version:

```
<script>
    var QunarUtil = new
    function() {
        var prefix = '/scripts/';
        var suffix = '';
        var host = '';
        if (location.host.indexOf('src.') != -1) {
            prefix = '/scripts/src/';
            host = 'http://hstatic.qunar.com';
            suffix = '.js';
        } else if (location.host.indexOf('enc.') != -1) {
            prefix = '/scripts/';
            host = 'http://hstatic.qunar.com';
            suffix = '.js';
        } else if (location.host.substring(0, 10) == 'sdev-') {
            prefix = location.host.substring(5, location.host.indexOf('.'));
            prefix = '/' + prefix.replace(/\-/ig, '/');
            host = 'http://hstatic.qunar.com';
            suffix = '.js';
        } else if (location.host.indexOf("h.qunar.com") != -1) {
            host = 'http://hstatic.qunar.com';
            suffix = '';
        }
        this.getScriptURL = function(name, isList) {
            if (name.charAt(0) != '/') return this.getScript(prefix + name, isList);
            else
            return this.getScript(name, isList);
        }
        this.getScript = function(src, isList) {
            return '<' + 'script type="text/javascript" src="' + host + src + (isList ? suffix : '.js') + '?' + __QUNARVER__ + '"></' + 'script>';
        }
        this.writeScript = function(name, isList) {
            document.write(this.getScriptURL(name, isList));
        }
        this.writeScriptList = function(list) {
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            document.write(this.getScriptURL(list[i]));
        }
        var cssRoot = '/styles/';
        this.writeCSS = function(cssList) {
            for (var i = 0; i < cssList.length; i++) {
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + cssRoot + cssList[i] + '?' + __QUNARVER__ + '">');
            }
        }
        this.writeStaticScript = function(src) {
            document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="' + src + '"></' + 'scr' + 'ipt>');
        }
        this.writeStaticList = function(src) {
            document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="' + src + suffix + '?' + __QUNARVER__ + '"></' + 'scr' + 'ipt>');
        }
    }
    $include = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            QunarUtil.writeScript(arguments[i], true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I bet someone would decipher that code for you, it is not readable.

Comment: Also instead of showing this code and asking for to tell you what it's supposed to do, please write your intentions so we should better understand what you are going to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a utility to load JavaScript and CSS files from http://hstatic.qunar.com.

As-is, the code will not work since it depends on a global variable called `__QUNARVER__`

Below is a verison of the code with inline documentation.

```
//Expose the variable QunarUtil into the global namespace, which is an instance of an anonymous function.
var QunarUtil = new function() {
    //set up internal variable in QunarUtil
    var prefix = '/scripts/';
    var suffix = '';
    var host = '';
    //Modify prefix, host & suffix if the current host (think webpage server
    //address in the browser) has 'src.' as part of it's hostname.
    if (location.host.indexOf('src.') != -1) {
        prefix = '/scripts/src/';
        host = 'http://hstatic.qunar.com';
        suffix = '.js';
    //Modify prefix, host & suffix if the current host has 'enc.' as part of it's hostname.
    } else if (location.host.indexOf('enc.') != -1) {
        prefix = '/scripts/';
        host = 'http://hstatic.qunar.com';
        suffix = '.js';
    //Modify prefix, host & suffix if the current host is 'sdev-' (and nothing
    //else since it is comparing a 5 char string with 10 char substring).
    } else if (location.host.substring(0, 10) == 'sdev-') {
        prefix = location.host.substring(5, location.host.indexOf('.'));
        prefix = '/' + prefix.replace(/\-/ig, '/');
        host = 'http://hstatic.qunar.com';
        suffix = '.js';
    //Modify prefix, host & suffix if the current host has 'h.qunar.com' as part of it's hostname.
    } else if (location.host.indexOf("h.qunar.com") != -1) {
        host = 'http://hstatic.qunar.com';
        suffix = '';
    }
    //Expose a method on the QunarUtil variable called getScriptURL.
    this.getScriptURL = function(name, isList) {
        if (name.charAt(0) != '/')
            return this.getScript(prefix + name, isList);
        else
            return this.getScript(name, isList);
    }
    //Expose a method on the QunarUtil variable called getScript.
    this.getScript = function(src, isList) {
        return '<' + 'script type="text/javascript" src="' + host +
               src + (isList ? suffix : '.js') + '?' + __QUNARVER__ + '"></' + 'script>';
    }
    //Expose a method on the QunarUtil variable called writeScript.
    this.writeScript = function(name, isList) {
        document.write(this.getScriptURL(name, isList));
    }
    //Expose a method on the QunarUtil variable called writeScriptList.
    this.writeScriptList = function(list) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        document.write(this.getScriptURL(list[i]));
    }
    //Set a new internal QunarUtil variable.
    var cssRoot = '/styles/';
    //Expose a method on the QunarUtil variable called writeCSS.
    this.writeCSS = function(cssList) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cssList.length; i++) {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + cssRoot + cssList[i] + '?' + __QUNARVER__ + '">');
        }
    }
    //Expose a method on the QunarUtil variable called writeStaticScript.
    this.writeStaticScript = function(src) {
        document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="' + src + '"></' + 'scr' + 'ipt>');
    }
    //Expose a method on the QunarUtil variable called writeStaticList.
    this.writeStaticList = function(src) {
        document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="' + src + suffix +
                       '?' + __QUNARVER__ + '"></' + 'scr' + 'ipt>');
    }
}
//Expose a global variable called $inclue which take an arbitrary number
//of JavaScript-file URLs as string arguments and loops over them to
//create a bunch of <script> tags using the QunarUtil.writeScript method.
$include = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        QunarUtil.writeScript(arguments[i], true);
    }
}
```

This code has nothing to do with the floating Google map you like, but it is probably used to load the code that does.

Comment: Thanks! Martin. So this script is intended to "hidden" the many js and css files that related to the floating google map.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a couple of functions to facilitate loading scripts and stylesheets from particular locations.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some kind of a script loader.

Comment: Hi guys, this script is copied fromhttp://hotel.qunar.com/city/shenzhen/q-%E5%8D%8E%E4%BE%A8%E5%9F%8E#fromDate=2011-01-18&toDate=2011-01-19&from=qunarHotel%7Cdiv ** I love the right side floating Google map, so I want know how it works, that's it. Thank you!